# magento - coupons code bulk import

Tags: php, magento

Hi I am trying to import coupons via csv to magento mysql and when i try the solution below i get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
>   in /home/wwwevolv/public_html/Lancaster/bulk.php on line 19

Any ideas? is it the code quotes?

Comment: What is the solution below?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom php script i have tried below link blog working fine need to some changes accourding to your requirement

http://www.gielberkers.com/bulk-import-coupon-codes-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, I am using this to import coupons:

```
<?php
$mageFilename = '../../app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Varien_Profiler::enable();

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

function getAllWbsites(){
    //get all wabsites
    $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection();
    $websiteIds = array();
    foreach ($websites as $website){
        $websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
    }
    return $websiteIds;
}
//read comments for each line
function generateRule($rulename, $desc, $status, $customerGroups, $couponCode, $fromDate, $toDate, $discountType, $discountAmount){

    $couponCheck = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('code',$couponCode)
                        ->load();
    $couponCheckArr = $couponCheck->getData();
    if(count($couponCheckArr)>0) {
        return false;
    }

    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $rule->setName($rulename);
    $rule->setDescription($desc);
    $rule->setFromDate($fromDate);//starting today
    if($toDate!="") {
        $rule->setToDate($toDate);//if you need an expiration date
    }
    $rule->setCouponCode($couponCode);
    $rule->setUsesPerCoupon(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon
    $rule->setUsesPerCustomer(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon for each customer
    $customerGroups = explode(',',$customerGroups);
    $rule->setCustomerGroupIds($customerGroups);//if you want only certain groups replace getAllCustomerGroups() with an array of desired ids
    $rule->setIsActive($status);
    $rule->setStopRulesProcessing(0);//set to 1 if you want all other rules after this to not be processed
    $rule->setIsRss(0);//set to 1 if you want this rule to be public in rss
    $rule->setIsAdvanced(1);//have no idea what it means :)
    $rule->setProductIds('');
    $rule->setSortOrder(0);// order in which the rules will be applied

    $rule->setSimpleAction($discountType);
    //all available discount types
    //by_percent - Percent of product price discount
    //by_fixed - Fixed amount discount
    //cart_fixed - Fixed amount discount for whole cart
    //buy_x_get_y - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)

    $rule->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);//the discount amount/percent. if SimpleAction is by_percent this value must be <= 100
    $rule->setDiscountQty(0);//Maximum Qty Discount is Applied to
    $rule->setDiscountStep(0);//used for buy_x_get_y; This is X
    $rule->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);//set to 1 for Free shipping
    $rule->setApplyToShipping(0);//set to 0 if you don't want the rule to be applied to shipping
    $rule->setWebsiteIds(getAllWbsites());//if you want only certain websites replace getAllWbsites() with an array of desired ids

    $conditions = array();
    $conditions[1] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => 1,
    'new_child' => ''
    );

    $rule->setData('conditions',$conditions);   
    $rule->loadPost($rule->getData());
    $rule->setCouponType(2);
    if($rule->save()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}

$fp = fopen('../data/coupon-import.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
$count = 0;
$countNotImpt = 0;
$i = 0;
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024,"\t")) {
    if($i>0) {
       $rulename = $csv_line[0];
       $desc = $csv_line[1];
       $status = $csv_line[2];
       $customerGroups = $csv_line[3];
       $couponCode = $csv_line[4];
       $fromDate = $csv_line[5];
       $toDate = $csv_line[6];
       $discountType = $csv_line[7];
       $discountAmount = $csv_line[8];
       if(generateRule($rulename, $desc, $status, $customerGroups, $couponCode, $fromDate, $toDate, $discountType, $discountAmount)) {
            $count++;
        }
        else{
            $countNotImpt++;
       }

   }

   $i++;
}
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
echo $count.' coupon successfully added.<br>';
echo $countNotImpt.' coupon already exits.<br>';

?>
```

CSV file format:

```
RULENAME    DESCRIPTION STATUS  CUSTOMERGROUP   COUPONCODE  FROMDATE    TODATE  DISCOUNTTYPE    DISCOUNTAMOUNT
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10ADZZ    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10CEED    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10DEGE    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10DHGD    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10EHGE    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10HBDB    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10ZCCB    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10FHGZ    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
Thank You   $ 10 OFF!   1   0,1 GC10EAFA    12/14/2009 11:25:17 AM      by_fixed    10
```

Hope will help!

Comment: Thanks alot for this, is there anyway you can apply the coupons to certain skus or product ids?

Comment: yes, you need to create sales rule condition to apply specific product. To apply coupon for specific product, you need to update SKU attribute settings. Set use for promotional and select product attribute for any specific coupon. I need to review condition array for product SKU specific.